# Generating words from trained RNN model: "Variable already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? "

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, recurrent-neural-network

So I implemented a RNN word generator model in jupytor notebook.
When I was trying to use the trained model to generate some words:

```
    with open(os.path.join(cfgs['save_dir'], 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
       saved_args = cPickle.load(f)

    with open(os.path.join(cfgs['save_dir'], 'words_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
       words, vocab = cPickle.load(f)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
       model = Model(saved_args, True)
       tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
       saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
       ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(cfgs['save_dir'])
       if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
           saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
           print(model.sample(sess, words, vocab, cfgs['n'], cfgs['prime'], cfgs['sample'], cfgs['pick'], cfgs['width']))
```

It works for the first time, but if I run the code again there is an error:

```
    ValueError: Variable rnnlm/softmax_w already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?
```

Right now I have to shut down the ipynb file then run the code to get a new sample.
How to change the code to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the model.sample function multiple times without a problem but everything else (creating the session, constructing the Model, loading the checkpoint) should only be run once. If you refactor your code then you won't see that error message anymore.